# Show matched results with WHERE IN() first then other results- MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following tables:

**user**

```
id  | Name    | ...
1   | John    |
2   | Richard |
3   | Michael |
```

**book**

```
id  | title | author| ...
1   | ABC   |  Z    |
2   | ABM   |  X    |
3   | IJK   |  W    |
4   | MNO   |  Z    |
5   | ABQ   |  Y    |
```

**fav_book**

```
user_id  | book_id
1        |   5   |  
1        |   4   | 
3        |   1   | 
3        |   2   | 
3        |   5   |
```

Now if `John` searches for a book titled `Ab`, I want to show his favourite book first in the search results then the others.

So output for `John` searching `Ab` should be

```
id  | title
5   | ABQ
1   | ABC
2   | ABM
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT id, title
FROM book 
WHERE id IN(5,4) AND title LIKE 'Ab%')
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, title
FROM book )
) tbl ORDER BY ???
```

SO how can I manipulate my `order by` clause to get the desired result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to tweak the `order by`:

```
SELECT id, title
FROM book 
WHERE title LIKE 'Ab%'
ORDER BY (id IN (5, 4)) DESC  -- put these first
```

MySQL treats a boolean like an integer in a numeric context.  "true" has the value 1 and "false" 0; that is why this puts the matching ids first.

You can add another `ORDER BY` key to order the values in each subset (favorites and non-favorites):

```
ORDER BY (id IN (5, 4)) DESC,  -- put these first
         id
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gordon Linoff. You are the best.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't want to hardcode the fav books for each user. 
If you want the results for `user_id = 1` and search for `title` beginning with `'Ab'`:

```
select 
  id, title
from book 
where title like 'Ab%'
order by (
  case when id in (select book_id from fav_book where user_id = 1) then 0
  else 1 end
), title
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5jxXirdDzGbNT5fKkqUa64/0)

Comment: That's true @forpas . Basically i have a php array (E.g. `$fav_books = [5,4]`) holding the favorite book ids.